# iOS: how to adjust positions of UI elements one by one properly by IB when some of them may change size?

Tags: iphone, ios

For example, on a UIView, from left to right there are three buttons:,button1,button2,button3.
When button 1 become wider, such as its width become twice as its original width, is there any interface builder way that can make button2&3 move right automatically?

sorry for I didn't make my question clear.

I mean such kind of size change: I push button1, then I change it's frame in my code, not caused by the change of text in butotn1. I want button2&3 to move right automatically, keeping the width of the gap between button 1 and 2 unchanged.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: What are the conditions that will make button 1 wider? Are you speaking of rotation or are you referring to using IB while designing the app, not running it?

Comment: Do you mean that when you sometimes change the text on your buttons, and they resize to fit the text, and that breaks your layout?  If so, it's best to make the buttons wide enough for their widest possible text.  If they can't all fit that way, reconsider the amount of text on your buttons.

Comment: @MikeZ sorry for I didn't make my self clear, now I've updated my question, I mean when I'm running the program and changed the button side in code.

Comment: @Dondragmer No, it's not that complicated, I just change my button size in code when user push a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your buttons are in a row at the bottom of the screen, consider using a `UIToolBar`.  Its `UIBarButtonItem` objects automatically adjust to fit each other's `width` changes.  For more generic cases, you'll need to recalculate positions and sizes as in Franklyn Weber's answer.

Answer (score 1):

IB can be used only for initional positioning of views.

True, you can also define autoresizing masks of the views but that's about it.

Any additional laying out should be done in code.

Answer (score 1):

I could be wrong, but I don't know of any way you can do this in IB. It's pretty straight forward in code though, just link the buttons to some IBOutlets and check the sizes of the images of the buttons (myUIImage.size), then adjust the frames of the buttons (do it in viewWillAppear).

Seen your edit - if you're adjusting its size using code, adjust its position too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - by using autoresizing masks. If you allow the margins to be flexible (no red lines connecting the frame to the superview's frame) and allow flexible width and height, the buttons will size and move proportionally.

Comment: I'll need to check this out - always willing to learn something new! Thanks.

Comment: Autosizing masks will make the view respond to changes in its superview, but won't solve the OP's problem of moving in response to other views at the same level in the view hierarchy.

Comment: It seems OP changed their question after I answered.